# selection in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, calendar

I want to make an application in C#  that has a part similar to "hotel booking"  using visual studio.

The user should be able to select multiple dates from a "table" that contains the calendar.
(like you select 5 data cells in excel, e.g. by holding the left mouse button down from the 01.01.2012 to 01.05.2012 )

I found some commercial solutions to this, but I want to do it myself.
I know that you can select multiple dates from the c# calendar, I don't want to use that.
I would like to use only c# in creating this app.

Please help me with the following:

**What should I look for constructing this table?** (I don't think I can't use buttons or a table...)

**I'm not looking for the complete solution, I just want a push in the right direction.**

P.S. The user should only select the cells (by holding down the left mouse button). After this his selection should be marked and do something without the user pushing another button.

E.g the user is selecting 01-05 and then the period is stored and the cells change colors and merge (have a single common label / text).

Comment: What frameworks are you using? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? etc...

Comment: Why don't you want to use the built-int .NET MonthCalendar?

Comment: I'm using WinForms 4.0  MonthCalendar is not what I want to do, it is not very user friendly... you have to hold shift, etc. What I want to do will be easier for the user.

Comment: Holy Object Orientation, Batman! You don't need to re-invent the calendar wheel just to get custom behavior! I strongly expect you can override and/or hide MonthCalendar keyboard & mouse events to do your own thing.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171534.aspx

Comment: Its not about re-inveting the wheel. I want another interface, not the calendar...Ty for your help, it is useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DataGridView, fill it with the date range you need and then allow multiselect.